# Converting existing Asp.Net web sites to Mobile version

Tags: asp.net, mobile

I have a existing web site which is developed in Asp.Net / AJAX 3.5, C#,
Now I need to make this site available in Mobile version. and I came across an open source tool

http://51degrees.mobi/Products/NETMobileAPI/AddtheNETMobileAPItoanExistingWebSite.aspx

But I am not sure  How do I integrate. this in my existing application.

Also my site is running in godaddy shared hosting server.

Answer (score 0):

Why bother? Most newer mobile devices handle full-featured sites just fine. And anything that doesn't exist will be, if anything, more capable. Unless you've got a specific use case for older phones on the site or a very big mobile footprint, its really not worth the trouble.

To answer your follow-on questions:

A) Image sizes are real tricky -- you can tell them to scale, but mobile is very bandwidth and processing power starved so you really need to make a separate size of image on the server for mobiles. Now this gets fun as there are a million or so screen sizes people use.

B) If you did Ajax right, that shouldn't matter -- graceful degradation is key.

Comment: The issues which I have got is Image size, AJAX etc...Is there any way to work around ?